# Connect through WebRTC to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, webrtc

I was trying to create a video conferencing application with WebRTC. But I ran into several problems:

1. I cannot create a p2p connection if at least one of the clients is behind symmetric NAT without the help of the TURN server.
2. If several people connected to each other at the same time, the application starts using all the available bandwidth.

Ok, I can't use p2p. I will use the server as an intermediary between clients. So the question is what is the best way to send the video / audio stream to the server and back to the clients.

I heard that you can connect each client to the server via WebRTC. Will the server be able to connect to the client behind symmetric NAT? Or maybe I should use WebSocket? If you provide code examples or links, I will be very grateful.

Note: I have a node.js express server.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to send it through the server you need an SFU.

I answered the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62046881/4051258