# Does google meet use WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, multipeer-connectivity, google-meet

I am new to webrtc development, I would like to create a conference room with multiples connections. I have read about webrtc and peer communication. I would like to know if google meet used one peer connection for every participants one another. If so, how can they handle 250 participants without draining the browser resources?

Comment: This might be useful: https://webrtchacks.com/hangout-analysis-philipp-hancke/

Comment: Also SFUs, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61703692/what-is-the-role-of-sfu-janus-mediasoup-or-medooze-on-a-webrtc-application `SFUs solve this problem by every peer sending only one stream to a mediaserver and letting that server do all the routing to the other peers.`

Comment: Both of them make clear the question, now I have to get to work on SFU setup

Answer (score 3):

For group calls, Google Meets does not use peer-to-peer, if that was the case, it would drain one's bandwidth very quickly and browser resources quickly.

Although I am not exactly sure about Meets' infrastructure, they most likely use a [Selective Forwarding Unit (SFU)](https://webrtcglossary.com/sfu/) to be able to handle lots of connections, since it's common practice for this sort of application.

The SFU works as a webrtc client server-side, and it basically just forwards the stream to clients that are requesting it browser-side.

Comment: so do you mean, for the goup calls, each client need 1 peer connection as broadcast, and n-1 peer connection as consumer to receive ?.

Comment: Pretty much, but not necessarily. More than one user could publish a stream, and the users that want to view that stream would subscribe to it. So, not necessarily 1 peer connection as broadcaster.